# How to Store Key-Value or One to Many User Settings in database (Xml, Json)?

Tags: mysql, xml, json, database-design, setting

Should we Keep application key-value settings data in Serialized manner in db like XML or JSON format.
**e.g.** user setting data can be kept in serialized manner **in a single nvarchar(2000) column**

Or I should keep them as table with columns like BELOW

**User ID, Setting Name, Setting Value**

1. *123,AssignedQuiz,Science*
2. *123,AssignedQuiz,Maths*
3. *456,AssignedQuiz,Geo*

Comment: I think A better table structure will be better than storing in serialized manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While storing in serialized manner it is difficult to update a single value in it. Instead You need to  update the column every time.
And if you store in table base it easy to update a single row or retrieve it from table.

You can define structure as:
Table:`setting`
column(settingid,setting_name,setting_value)

Table: `user_settings`
column(userid,settingid)

Comment: but ms sql server supports XML data type and indexing and querying on it, also xpath updates, selects so How about it...?

Comment: As per your requirement list out all pros and cons and than decide on that. It is difficult here to decide as I don't know what you have and you don't.

Comment: marking this as an answer...will ask other question (when do we use database XML data type..???) in another thread.

Comment: Than U suresh! but One last question...will this structure work fine for **10 million users*100 Settings**??

Comment: I agree with Surersh.. Using table approach reduces workload.

Comment: @abksharma: yes definitely, this structure will work fine with more 10M user and their settings.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL STRUCTURE I had
But will this structure be scalable upto 10 million users*100 Settings = 1 Billion settings Mysql??
YES IT WILL!!!

**SettingType TABLE**

```
   SettingTypeId    UNSIGNED SMALLINT(2)
    SettingName VARCHAR(100)
    SettingDescription  VARCHAR(300)
    Created DATETIME
    LastUpdated TIMESTAMP
    CreatedBy   UNSIGNED INT(4)
    ModifiedBy  UNSIGNED INT(4)
    Deleted BIT
    Disabled    BIT
    RecordVersion   UNSIGNED INT(4)
```

Final structure:-

**Setting TABLE**

```
   SettingId    UNSIGNED INT(4)
    SettingTypeId   UNSIGNED SMALLINT(2)
    UserId  UNSIGNED INT(4)
    SettingValue    VARCHAR(1000)
    Created DATETIME
    LastUpdated TIMESTAMP
    CreatedBy   UNSIGNED INT(4)
    ModifiedBy  UNSIGNED INT(4)
    Deleted BIT
    Disabled    BIT
    RecordVersion   UNSIGNED INT(4)
```